# Can I say that I am utilizing same terms & conditions and privacy policy of this (xyz) website?

Tags: privacy, terms-of-service

I am running a service `A` that uses some other service `B`. The company `L` also provides and uses the service `B` for themself as well for service `K`.

Can I say on my service website `A` that my service utilizes their terms & conditions and Privacy Policy and forward the links to service `K` terms & conditions and privacy policy?

The service `K`'s terms and Conditions and Privacy policies have their name on them so how much that matter or what kind of change should I put on the website to reflect this correctly?

Comment: What country/jurisdiction?

Comment: Internationally,I am from India

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that's definitely not a good idea.

A privacy policy/terms document is supposed to reflect your situation:

- local laws for both PP/Terms
- describe exactly what your company does for both PP/Terms
- and identify you as a company

What you will do however, is to describe the service providers you're using, in that case you would link to them, from your own documents.

If you google you will find a lot of templates out there offered for free (however tbh only a few of them are actually good, and you don't know if they cover your situation well - very few of them were written with India in mind, on top of that) - or you will find generators that help with generating terms and privacy-related docs for you. Pick one that has a sustainable business model so you know that they'll be around and what they do has legs.

I'll personally be writing text to cover India this year, but can't tell you when yet, depends on the release of the new Indian data protection regulations.

Comment: Your points make visual clear to understand that why not. Despite from company's mutual confirmations to use T&C or PP (that means no copyright issues, I guess), this covers that part too or I mean does assume that, thanks for explaining

Comment: Example for what fits a situation: A local RPG convention has Terms of Service that are almost indistinguishable of a Bridal-Attire-Fair... but the younger Anime-convention around did not have any ToS but for "we say if you have to go, don't be a dick, don't do anything naughty or illegal or obscene. No photos without allowance."

Comment: I won't be going on that path then, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

- It would be terribly risky for you to simply link another company's terms of service. What if they take their server down? What if they change their terms? You would not even know when exactly the changes were made.
- Copying their terms means you might run into *copyright* issues on the text.

Either pay a lawyer to write your ToS for you, or see if you can find something in the public domain.

Comment: got it, thank you O.M. That makes sense